# How to find name of the departments in which all employees working in the department have a salary greater than 30000

Tags: database, relational-algebra

I'm struggling with this Relational Algebra question. Below are the relations involved in the question. (**Bold** attributes are primary keys.)

> Employee (**eid**, ename , salary , dept, address)
>   Department (**deptNo**, dname, building, mgrID)
>
> fk **dept** references Department(**deptNo**)
>   fk **mgrID** references Employee(**eid**)

This is the Question:

> Print the name of the departments in which all employees working in the department have a salary greater than 30000.

And this is what I tried:

(G is an aggregation function symbol.)

```
NewRelation(dname, empCount) <- dname G count(eid) (Employee ⋈ dept=deptNo Department)
∏ dname (σ salary>30000 (NewRelation))
```

But I guess my approach is not right. What is right? (Please use the same symbols I have used when writing the algebra.)

Comment: @VadimKotov When you edit please try to edit as much as you can. See my edit. I realize you may not be able to improve the English. (I left some poor English in the assignment question because it's supposedly a quote & I didn't want to change it very much.)

Comment: Hi. Please give a reference or definition for the RA you are using, there are many. Eg some people might recognize G but it is not standard. Also you use it wrong, read its definition. Check my code typo fixes. Please read & act on hits googling 'stackexchange homework'. Explain what parts/subqueries you think are right & why & what they return & same for the wrong. Eg: Why are you counting? What does it have to do with the answer? What does? PS Constraints (PKs, CKs, FKs etc) are not needed to query. So there's no reason to give them. So there's something you don't understand about that.

Comment: Hint 1: that pair of Foreign Keys mean there are no 'empty' departments, and all employees belong to some department.
Hint 2: you therefore do not need a Group or count operation, because ...
Hint 3: If all employees have a salary greater than x, then no employee has a salary less or equal x.

Comment: @AntC The FK constraints imply neither that there are no departments with no employees nor that all employees belong to some department. They say Employee departments are Departments & Department managers are Employees. Lots of business rules might or might not hold to combine with those & also we don't know the exact table meanings. There could be Departments with no employees. There could be employees with no Departments--though not in Employees. In turn your "therefore" is unsound. (A constraint does always imply that some queries that could otherwise return different result don't.)

Comment: Thanks @philipxy, yes I acknowledged and discussed in my answer below that FK `mgrID references Employee(eid)` doesn't in fact guarantee no 'empty' departments. ...

Comment: ... To claim "There could be employees with no Departments" goes against the FK `dept references Department(deptNo)`; then to substantiate your claim by hypothesising there are employees "not in Employees" is the pickiest sort of nit-picking. You're turning it from an exercise in Relational Algebra (which was already ambiguous) into abstract ontology -- which I doubt was the question-setters intent. How do we find "all the departments in which all employees ..." if there might be employees in a department who are not recorded in Employees? That makes any query impossible. Is that your answer?

Comment: @AntC On the contrary, you are making unjustified assumptions re the application & table meanings, while I am just 1. telling you what the FKs say in terms of table values & 2. assuming only that the query can be reasonably answered by the 2 tables. Your query shows all we need is Employees except for salaried employee department names! My eg's are consistent with minimal common sense table meanings. And neither one is "there might be employees in a department who are not recorded in Employees"--I'd agree that unsalaried employees in departments makes the question unanswerable by the 2 tables.

Answer (score 0):

> Q) Print the name of the department in which all employees working in
>   the department is having a salary greater than 30000.

You can use Query for in MySQL.

```
SELECT D.dname FROM
Department D WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) 
                    FROM Employee E 
                    WHERE E.dept = D.deptNo AND
                            E.salary < 30000) <= 0
```

Comment: Thanks but I need relation algebra. Thanks for you try

Comment: Yes I understand. Good Luck. :) @JananathBanuka

Comment: There's a bug and a maybe-bug here: what if there's a department with an employee who earns exactly 30000? (and any other employees earn exactly 30000 or less.) What if there's a department with no employees at all? (that might happen, my Hint 1 above is not water-tight.)

Comment: EDIT: I put a bug in my bug-correction. Shows how easy it is to mess this up. That should be: what if there's a department with an employee who earns exactly 30000? (and any other employees earn exactly 30000 or _more_.)

Answer (score 0):

> Q. Print the name of the departments in which all employees working in the department have a salary greater than 30000.

Note: only the departmnt name, not anything about the employees.

```
NewRelation(dname) <- ∏ dname
    ( Department ⋈ deptNo=dept
         (∏ dept (Employee) - ∏ dept (σ salary<=30000 (Employee)) ) )
```

I've used the same symbols and 'dialect' as your O.P. As @philipxy says, there are many variants. In particular using `⋈` like that for an equi-join is not something I would do. (And there's a more suitable operator: semidifference.)

**Explanation:** (working from right to left)

`(σ salary<=30000 (Employee))` gets employees (and their `dept`) earning not greater than 30000.

`∏ dept` projects that down to just the `dept` number. It's the departments we *don't* want.

`∏ dept (Employee) -` where `-` is minus, takes the departments we don't want away from the full set of `dept`s.

`Department ⋈ deptNo=dept` equi-joins those `dept`s to their Department. In this usage, `⋈` is acting as a restriction to just the `dept`s with all Employees earning enough.

`∏ dname` takes just the Department name, as requested. So we'll get one tuple per Department. (Actually one tuple per distinct Department name, just in case there are same-named Departments.)

There might be a catch to this question: if a Department has no employees, do we say all of them earn >30000? Equally we could say all of them earn <=30000. I've assumed no Department is 'empty' -- see my Hint 1.

For this query, empty Departments won't appear. Actually the FK `mgrID references Employee(eid)` doesn't guarantee none are empty. Perhaps the employee identified by `mgrID` is in a different `dept` to the `deptNo`?

Roughly equivalent SQL is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT dname
FROM Department D
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                  FROM Employee E
                  WHERE deptNo = dept
                    AND salary <= 30000 )
```

This takes the opposite side on the empty Department question: empty Departments *do* appear. (The sort of catch that question-setters love to torture you with.)

Answer (score 0):

Temp <- Employee⋈<sub>dept = deptNo</sub>Department

Temp2(deptNo,dname,Min_Salary) <- deptNo,dname G<sub>MIN(Salary)</sub>(Temp)

∏<sub>dname</sub>(σ<sub>Min_Salary > 30000)</sub>(Temp2)

If the employee with the least salary in a department has a salary greater than 30000, this means that all employees in that department have a salary greater than 30000.